# How do I show keywords and a search box under my site's Google results?

Tags: asp.net, seo

I saw on the google when search "code project", some keywords and a text field and a button to search that google has generated for "code project" keyword also for "manchester university" in the same way.

How is it possible to show key words and text field/button for our website on google? As it shows for "code project" and "manchester university" etc.

please visit google and search "manchester university" u'll see:

StudentNet Job Opportunities
PostGraduate StaffNet
etc..
and
textfield/ and a button

I want this kind of result for my site from Google!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Google calls the search-box-within-a-search-result "teleporting". Unfortunately, Google decides when to display this additional search box, not you. You can read their blog post about the feature **[here](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2008/03/search-within-site-tale-of.html)**.

The text links under search results are called "sitelinks". Google also decides when to display these, although you can ask Google not to show them if you want. You can read more about this feature **[here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334)**.

Comment: +1. In addition to this, I would just mention that if you do manage to acquire "Sitelinks", they do not appear for all search terms. They are granted to you if your website appears to be "The Authority" in respect of the specific search phrase entered.